# Foreach loop does not compare

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am somewhat of a programming noob, and i was stuck with an issue trying to echo out only a few items of my array instead of all the items in the array.

So what i have is a products.php file that contains my array $products, i am now trying to call this array from my index page, and i want to not only call the array, but to have the products in the array to list the last 4 products instead of all of them.

so now in my index.php i have created this code:

```
$total_products = count($products);
$position = 0;
$list_view_html = "";
foreach($products as $product_id => $product) {
$position = $position + 1;
if($total_product - $position < 4){
$list_view_html = $list_view_html . get_list_view_html($product_id,$product);
}
} 
echo $list_view_html;
```

now when i save and load the webpage, i still see all the products listed and not the 4 i should be seeing.

from what i understand, i am counting the products in the array, starting the loop at 0, looping through the array and then increment up the count +1. i then am stating that if the products in the loops position is less than the 4 items i want to be shown.

i know the code might not be the best way efficiency wise, or that it has certain critiques. I appreciate all the help, but i just need to figure out why i cant get this to work.

any help is appreciated, the less condescending the better.

thanks guys

Comment: typo: $total_products and $total_product

Comment: @Akam Oh. I didn't read your comment before.

Comment: Thanks Akam, good find! Much appreciated

Comment: the goal is to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo. Change the if to:

```
if($total_products - $position < 4){
```

Note that the var's name is `$total_products` . You are using `$total_product` without the 's' and the end.

Comment: Your awesome ! shame on me all of that was right and ofcourse it was in the details of a typo. Thanks hek2

Comment: You are welcome. Check also the answer of @jeroen

Answer (score 3):

That seems a very complicated way to get the last 4 items.

I would recommend using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$last_four = array_slice($products, 0, -4);
```

and a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: Nice ! thats a neat little trick. but can i ask why is it -4 ?

Comment: @Justin Enayati 4 from the end. +4 is 4 from the start.